# TestNG : dependsOnGroups stopped execution of tests

Tags: jenkins, testng

I have a bunch of tests that belong to group **regression** and another set of tests that belong to group **Set1**.

I want **Set1** to run after **regression** has completed.

So I added

```
@Test(singleThreaded = true, ignoreMissingDependencies = false, dependsOnGroups = "regression", alwaysRun = true)
```

to class **Set1** tests.

My TestNg has included tests from both the groups.

When I run tests using

```
maven clean verify
```

Only **regression** group tests run, after that tests stop.

This happens only when I trigger the job in Jenkins, if I test the dependency locally by running a test or two, it is working as expected.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Maven are you using locally and which version of Maven are you using on Jenkins?

Comment: I have 3.5.2 in both. Also. My local is OSX where as Jenkins is on Windows.

Comment: Can you show the relevant diff between the two builds (in verbose mode if needed)?

Comment: I doubt that would be possible. because Jenkins console output would not make Sense here.

Comment: how are you grouping the tests ? In Xml or directly in method annotation?

Comment: Im using testing annotations.